# File added to project doesn't get added to packages

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I'm creating customized binary versions of OpenStack nova packages (lp:nova) using their packaging scripts (lp:~openstack-ubuntu-packagers/ubuntu/natty/nova/ubuntu).

I create binaries by doing:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -b -rfakeroot -tc -uc -D
```

This creates a set of packages (python-nova, nova-common, nova-compute, ...).

In our customized version of the code (lp:~usc-isi/nova/hpc-trunk), we recently merged in some changes from another branch, and there's now a new file in our repository that wasn't in upstream: `nova/virt/cpuinfo.xml.template`.

This file isn't getting added to any of the packages, where it should be added to python-nova.

Why wouldn't dpkg-buildpackage be including this file? A more basic question: how does dpkg-buildpackage determine which files go in which packages? Is it related at all to the debian/watch file? This contains some URLs that are pointing to the upstream project.

```
version=3
http://launchpad.net/nova/+download http://launchpad.net/nova/.*/nova-(.*)\.tar\.gz
http://nova.openstack.org/tarballs/ nova-(.*).tar.gz
```

Comment: log/watch is not related, it just defines how to check for new versions of the source distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't notice the MANIFEST.in file in the top-level of the source tree (not in debian directory).